# How to query a RealmList inside a RealmObject (in Android)

Tags: android, realm, realm-list

I've been trying to query a RealmList inside a RealmObject however I always got this error:

> Invalid query: field 'field_obbject' in class 'ClassRealm' is
>   of invalid type 'STRING_LIST'.

how can I do queries based on a RealmList element? 
checking if this is empty? 
checking if one of the strings is equal to "whatever string" ??

I've been using **Realm.contains()** but it returns this error.

Update:

```
 val result = realmInstance
                    .where<CarRealm>(CarRealm::class.java)
                    .contains(CarRealm.BRANDS_NAMES, name.toLowerCase())
                    .findAll()
```

so **CarRealm** has a RealmList of brands.

Comment: Show your current code, or we don't have a chance to help you.

Comment: You cannot query elements inside primitive RealmLists.

Comment: I've just updated it

Comment: You should nag Realm for it at https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/5361  and https://github.com/realm/realm-object-store/issues/513

Answer (score 0):

I manage to solve this changing the RealmList type by a class with has an String attribute.  I couldn't find other way to filter by the content of the list.

Comment: can you put a example here